# Make C# Search Hard-Drive Exclude Directory

Tags: c#, directory

Program goes through directories and prints Avi files to textbox

```
    public FileList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Sets Drive Choices
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo d in drives)
        {
            driveChoice.Items.Add(d);
        }
    }

    //Find Video Files
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        String path = driveChoice.Text;
        if (path != "C:\\")
        {
            String[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.avi*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (String file in allfiles)
            {
                tbFileList.Text = tbFileList.Text + file + "\r\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

    }
}
```

When ran I get an error.

**Unauthorized Access 'I:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-1332477098-3306142970-3529014387-1000\'**

Can I set the program to just skip 'I:\$RECYCLE.BIN'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to switch to a recursive solution or some other loop rather than using 'AllDirectories'. That way you can provide some skip logic.

see this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974

and this code snippet from that page:

```
void DirSearch(string sDir) 
    {
        try 
        {
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)) 
            {
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, txtFile.Text)) 
                {
                    lstFilesFound.Items.Add(f);
                }
                DirSearch(d);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
        }
    }
```

In that code you would just check your sDir for the values you want to skip.

Comment: You're still going to run into potential `SecurityException` or `UnauthorizedAccessException` instances being thrown with the code above.  If you want to skip over folders your security doesn't all you to access, I recommend wrapping the inner `foreach` and recursive `DirSearch(d)` block in a `try {} catch {}` block filtered to those exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Now there is no way to have the `AllDirectories` option skip specific directories or ignore exceptions that occur from traversing.  You will need to manually search the directory structure and deal with errors that occur

Answer (score 0):

`if !filePath.Contains("I:\$RECYCLE.BIN")`

Answer (score 0):

Use a lambda statement to exclude the system directories:

```
public FileList()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Sets Drive Choices
    DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    foreach (DriveInfo d in drives)
    {
        driveChoice.Items.Add(d);
    }
}

//Find Video Files
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    String path = driveChoice.Text;
    if (path != "C:\\")
    {
        DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        var rootFiles = root.GetFiles("*.avi");
        var rootDirs = root.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(d => !d.Name.Equals("System Volume Information") && !d.Name.Equals("$RECYCLE.BIN"));
        foreach (var file in rootFiles)
        {
            tbFileList.Text = tbFileList.Text + file.FullName + "\r\n";
        }
        foreach (var dir in rootDirs)
        {
            foreach (var dirFile in dir.GetFiles("*.avi", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                tbFileList.Text = tbFileList.Text + dirFile.FullName + "\r\n";
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the usage of the Lambda expression of excluding both folders from the returned string list in VS 2017. I observed something strange. If the lambda expression is directly added to the retrieval of the directories as in the string shown above the list still returns $RECYCLEBIN, however SVI folder is not returned. In order to make the lambda working correctly I needed to separate the 2 actions i.e:

```
 var allDirs = rootDir.GetDirectories("*",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
 var filteredDirs = allDirs.Where(d=> !d.Name.Equals("System Volume Information") && !d.Name.Equals("$RECYCLE.BIN"));
```